# Firebase FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() returns null with a certain Gmail address

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

From the title, you would think that there is a published solution to my problem, but in fact I believe I read everything pertinent to my question, but nothing quite matched up. Here's what I've got:

First of all, this problem has never happened in my app before today, nor did my sign-in change in any way: same Google sign-in code, same account. Everything the same for the past three months, as long as I've been testing. And, as far as I can tell, the problem only occurs with a single account. When the user begins the sign-in process, they are presented with a choice of accounts to sign in with; in this case, I selected the first user:

[image]

Next, Google authenticates the user and we arrive here in the code:

[image]

So the question is, why did Firebase suddenly stop providing the display name (and the photo URL)? From the first screenshot, it's clear that the user has a specified name and photo. Apart from that, FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isAnonymous() is false, as expected. Any ideas on why this suddenly broke would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply updating my name and photo URL using UserProfileChangeRequest() and the name and photo URL of my Google account, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395256/firebase-getdisplayname-returns-empty):

```
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    sendFirebaseEvent(FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_EVENT, FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_KEY, acct.getId());
    // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
    showProgressDialog();
    googleAccount = acct;
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        sendFirebaseEvent(FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_EVENT, FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_RESULT_KEY, "Success");
                        launchNextActivity();
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        sendFirebaseEvent(FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_EVENT, FIREBASE_GOOGLE_AUTH_RESULT_KEY, task.getException().getMessage());
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
}
private void launchNextActivity() {
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser mUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (mUser.getDisplayName() == null || mUser.getDisplayName().length() == 0) {
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(googleAccount.getDisplayName())
                .setPhotoUri(googleAccount.getPhotoUrl())
                .build();
        mUser.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
    }
}
```